# Summarize two columns that have a many-to-many relationship in an SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following database tables `Transactions` and `Payments`. The data is structured as such that both Transactions and Payments have a many-to-many relationship, which are joined together in a query as such:

```
SELECT Transactions.Id, Payments.Id, Transactions.Amount
FROM Transactions 
LEFT JOIN Payments ON Transactions.Id = Payments.TransactionId 

| Transactions.Id | Payments.PaymentId | Transactions.Amount |
| ----------------| -------------------| --------------------|
| 3492            | 123456             | 123                 |
| 3492            | 123457             | 123                 |
| 3493            | 123458             | 300                 |
| 3494            | 123459             | 10                  |
| 3495            | 123459             | 25                  |
```

I want to be able to simplify the table into something like below (if this is at all even possible in SQL)

```
| Transactions.Id | Payments.PaymentId | Transactions.Amount |
| ----------------| -------------------| --------------------|
| 3492            | 123456, 123457     | 123                 |
| 3493            | 123458             | 300                 |
| 3494, 3495      | 123459             | 35                  |
```

...or even without the third column (if it reduces complexity)

```
| Transactions.Id | Payments.PaymentId |
| ----------------| -------------------|
| 3492            | 123456, 123457     |
| 3493            | 123458             |
| 3494, 3495      | 123459             |
```

What I have so far:

```
SELECT
Transactions.Id, 
   STUFF((SELECT '; ' + CAST(Payments.Id as varchar)
    FROM Payments 
    WHERE Payments.TransactionId = Transactions.Id
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [PaymentIds]
FROM Transactions

| Transactions.Id | PaymentIds         |
| ----------------| -------------------|
| 3492            | 123456, 123457     |
| 3493            | 123458             |
| 3494            | 123459             |
| 3495            | 123459             |
```

How do I add Transactions.Id into a comma separated list as well?
I am using SQL Server 12.0.2000.8

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/020cd8/5/0)

Comment: Could you share what version of SQL Server? Also the first query isn't reality because you should get an error about `Transactions.Amount` not being in the `GROUP BY` - maybe that's meant to be `SUM(Transactions.Amount)`? Can you share the source tables/data instead of the result of a join/aggregation? Preferably in a [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle)? And by "simplify the table" do you mean you want to change table structure, or did you mean you want to simplify the output of the query?

Comment: I tried the fiddle and (after a long delay) it breaks, [just like it does here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c3fe8bf797b7064c77a90b5a60ce0e40). I'm not quite sure how you coerced results out of sqlfiddle (oh, I see, MySQL was incorrectly selected, and it lets you do wacky things like leave columns out of GROUP BY)...

Comment: Thanks for responding, I've edited the fiddle (I hope it works?) As for the GROUP BY, I've removed it in the question post (it was a leftover from when I was simplifying my local query). Apologies!

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=7d2aa911c5ecb1e49b44113472a3a4e2)

Comment: There really should not have been a group by in the original query anymore -- it's a quirk of the data. 

When multiple payments has a relationship to a single transaction, the transactions.amount is supposed to be the total amount of both payments (payments 123456 and 123457 share the amount of 123); whereas if a single transaction has many payments then the totals have to be summed (like in Transaction 3494 and 3495 = 35). 

The logic is actually confusing (not my design) but at the very least what I want to achieve is the 2nd table so I can proceed with using the query results

Comment: Thanks, and just to be clear, the new fiddle suggests you store the same amounts in both the transaction and the payment table, I realize this is a coincidence but isn't it possible that some payments wouldn't match the source transaction exactly?

Comment: ...even I got confused with trying to explain the way the calculations work on this table haha. I've edited the one comment where I try to explain how the totals are supposed to work. And yes, that's actually what I am trying to work on now -- in the actual database there are rows where the amount values are incorrect between rows based on their supposed calculations. What I'm trying to do first is get the data in order so I can figure out which are the erring transaction/payment pairs.

Comment: And further clarification, if a transaction has two payments, they'll always be identical? If not, do you want the min or the max or the avg or ...? And if a payment applies to two transactions, you always want the SUM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you have to take two passes in order to aggregate the payments per transaction and then the transaction per payment aggregate. This assumes (based on the sample data and desired output) that when a payment applies to multiple transactions, you want the sum, but when a transaction has multiple payments, you want the max (or they'll always be the same in which case max works just fine?):

```
;WITH FirstPass AS 
(
  SELECT t.Id, pId = STUFF(
    (SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(11), p.Id)
      FROM dbo.Payments AS p
      WHERE p.TransactionId = t.Id
      ORDER BY p.Id
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', 
        N'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''),
    Amount = MAX(t.Amount)
  FROM dbo.Transactions AS t
  GROUP BY t.Id
)
SELECT [Transactions.Id] = STUFF(
  (SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(11), fp.Id)
    FROM FirstPass AS fp
    WHERE fp.pId = FirstPass.pId
    ORDER BY fp.pId
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', 
        N'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''),
  [Payments.PaymentId] = FirstPass.pId,
  Amount = SUM(FirstPass.Amount)
FROM FirstPass 
GROUP BY FirstPass.pId;
```

Output:

| Transactions.Id | Payments.PaymentId | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3492 | 123456, 123457 | 123.00 |
| 3493 | 123458 | 300.00 |
| 3494, 3495 | 123459 | 35.00 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4548e41c759ef4aea7dcaf9ee1f16952)

On SQL Server 2017+ (or Azure SQL Database) this becomes much simpler, though still a little convoluted for this specific use case. This doesn't help you right now, but could help other readers today, future readers, or even future you:

```
;WITH FirstPass AS 
(
  SELECT t.Id, ca.pId, Amount = MAX(t.Amount)
  FROM dbo.Transactions AS t
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT pId = STRING_AGG(p.Id, ', ')
      FROM dbo.Payments AS p
      WHERE p.TransactionId = t.Id
  ) AS ca GROUP BY t.Id, ca.pId
)
SELECT [Transactions.Id] = STRING_AGG(Id, ', '),
  [Payments.PaymentId] = pId,
  Amount = SUM(Amount)
FROM FirstPass 
GROUP BY pId;
```

Same output:

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c486f5a743f2270102ba5a8257646320)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed; MAX works for the scenario where a transaction has many payments. Thanks Aaron!

Answer (score 0):

The following code generates the output you want

```
WITH cte1 AS(
   SELECT 
       Transactions.Id AS TransactionID, 
       Payments.Id AS PaymentID,
       max(Transactions.amount) Amount
   FROM Transactions 
   LEFT JOIN Payments ON Transactions.Id = Payments.TransactionId 
   GROUP BY Transactions.Id,Payments.Id),
   
   
cte2 AS(
  SELECT

       STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(t2.TransactionID as varchar(100)) 
       FROM cte1 t2
       WHERE t2.PaymentID = t1.PaymentID
       FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'')TransactionID,
     
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(t2.PaymentID as varchar(100)) 
       FROM cte1 t2
       WHERE t2.TransactionID = t1.TransactionID
       FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'')PaymentID,
     
       (SELECT sum(Amount)
       FROM cte1 t2 
       WHERE t2.PaymentID = t1.PaymentID
       GROUP BY PaymentID)Amount
     
    
     
   FROM cte1 t1
)

SELECT TransactionID,PaymentID,Amount
FROM cte2
GROUP BY TransactionID,PaymentID,Amount
```

***[result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=039b0f65842bfade53908d532f08edfc)***